# Is objectual a word?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, style-manuals

Is *objectual* a word? I could not find it in Merriam Webster.

I am trying to use it in a sentence like this:

> ***A phrase*** signifies the objectual nature of ***thing in question***.

Would I be stretching the grammaticallity of the word *object*?

Comment: What do you think _objectual_ means?

Comment: The idiomatic word is *objectionable*; or do you mean something else?

Comment: In your sentence, *objectual* is just an adjective. It could mean *perceived, intended, effective* or even *leathery.* What would you like it to mean?

Comment: I have put up the sentence I am intending to use the word in. @KillingTime

Comment: Words don't have 'grammaticality', Frank; _constructions_ are either grammatical or ungrammatical (or argued over). Perhaps 'Does W exist as a word and and if so, is it used correctly in this sentence ... ... ... ... W ... ..., with the meaning ... ... ...?' // I assume you're saying something like 'In the catalogue, a phrase describing the object is added.' If not, please could you add a more precise sentence or explanation.

Comment: You could use *objective* but it has several different meanings in English, so isn't particularly a great choice.

Comment: I did not know of the word "objectual", but by googling I immediately learned a definition of it.  Instead of relying on "Merriam Webster" (which is a company that produces both abridged and unabridged dictionaries), I find it most useful to look things up at the multiple dictionary site onelook.com, and to google the word.

Comment: You can always use 'object' as a much more pleasing sounding noun-attribute. "A phrase signifies the __object nature__ of a thing in question.".. if that is indeed the meaning you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Objectual*, an obsolete or rare word, is probably not what you’re looking for.

But there is a word — one noun for your adjective/noun duo — that might work:

> *A phrase signifies the **objectness** of the thing in question.*

> **objectness**, *n.*
>  The state or quality of being objective; the fact of being an object.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

The suffix *-ness* is normally added to adjectives to form nouns, but we also do this:

> Appended to words of other parts of speech to form nouns (often nonce
> words or terms in philosophy) meaning the state/quality/measure of the
> idea represented by these words.
>  ‎*that* + *‎-ness* →
> ‎*thatness*
> *tree* + *‎-ness* → ‎*treeness*
>  ‎*thug* + *‎-ness* → ‎*thugness*
>  <sub>Source: [Wiktionary
> —ness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ness)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Objectual has two meanings in English. The first is obsolete:

OED

> **objectual**, adj.
>
> **†1. Of the nature of an object; that is the purpose or object of some action; that is a material or external object.** Obsolete.
>
> 1606   True Relation Proc. at Arraignm. Late Traitors 339   *Without
> any other point or scope objectual to move unto.*
>
> 1624   T. Adams Temple 37   *Concerning the materiall Temple,
> externall or obiectuall Idols.*

The current meaning is specialised and rare:

> **2.** *Logic.* **Referring or relating to a material object, as opposed to a symbol or fictive referent.**
>
> 1936   Jrnl. Symbolic Logic 1 112   *The book has five parts,
> corresponding to the five departments into which the author conceives
> logic as falling: logical grammar, formal propositional logic,
> objectual logic, modal logic, and categorial logic.*
>
> 1969   W. V. Quine Ontological Relativity & Other Ess. iv. 105
> *Substitutional quantification and the truth functions are, in brief, far and away more recognizable behaviorally than classical
> quantification, or what we may call objectual quantification.*
>
> 1986   J. J. C. Smart in E. LePore Truth & Interpretation v. 97
> *According to this view, Dickens was pretending (or half-pretending) to operate an objectual and extensional semantics, not actually
> operating an intensional one or a non-classical one.*

Comment: Does OP's intended sentence make any sense? Is he wise to use it?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fortunately, the OP did not ask that question, and so it does not require an answer. Any answer would have to be a comment. He has not "stretched the grammaticallity" [sic] (whatever that means.)

Comment: @Greybeard Thank you for your response. I would be grateful if you said a little bit about the intended use I put up in the body of the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, it is impossible for anybody to determine whether the word is used meaningfully or wisely in the sample sentence, because we don't know what the 'thing in question' is and what its 'nature' is, that the OP is trying to capture by the word *objectual*. The OP has to judge for himself whether what he intended by the word fits the dictionary definition.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, I agree. I've just CV-d as my request for clarification hasn't been addressed.

Comment: @FrankBooth In common with others here, I have no idea what your intended use is or what you think it means. What is the context? If something is "big" it is comparatively voluminous or of a size greater than expectations. If something is "objectual" what properties does it possess?

Answer (score 2):

Even if it *is* a word, it's used very rarely or not at all ... you can't find it in any non-paywalled online dictionary.
What you can find though, is a word with similar spelling, "objectal".
It means:

> **objectal** [adjective]
>
> 1. Having the form of an object or objects; pertaining to the physical form of something; material.
> 2. Concerning the cognitive representation of an object outside the self.

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/objectal)]

Comment: Hello, Paradox. Please add the reference: a linked attribution (this helps others, and copyright issues are reduced).

Comment: Is this okay now?